# How can I SSH to a PowerShell on Windows and keep a set of working arrow keys?

Tags: ssh, powershell

I can do this to directly enter a PowerShell

```
ssh foobar 'powershell'
```

, but in this shell, arrow keys won't work.

It works if I just:

```
ssh foobar
```

..and then enter PowerShell, by typing `powershell`. Here arrow keys work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to be a problem with windows software, not UNIX/Linux

Comment: well, we first need to know if putting 'command' at the end of ssh command it the way to launch a command after it has connected or are there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `ssh foobar 'powershell'` is the main way to launch a command after SSH has connected... but there is a caveat: by default, when you specify a command like that, the OpenSSH client *will initialize the session as a non-interactive one*.

That essentially means no PTY device at the remote end, just a straight pipe from the remote `sshd` to the remote shell and the executed command. Also no `$TERM` variable, and ideally no output from login scripts to mess things up, so you will be able to efficiently pipe things between systems over SSH. But this will make interactive tools unhappy: for example, as you noticed, the arrow keys won't work, because the remote side has no clue what kind of terminal keycode sequences the local end is going to send for the arrow keys.

You can fix that by explicitly requesting TTY allocation when you specify a remote command on the SSH command line:

```
ssh -t foobar 'powershell'
```

Adding the `-t` option causes the SSH client to request the remote `sshd` to fully set up the remote end for interactive use, even when you are specifying a command for the remote side.

And since there are no characters in `powershell` that would have a special meaning for the local shell, you can omit the single quotes too.

```
ssh -t foobar powershell
```